# How to update a subclassed variable

Tags: c++, qt

```
class Label : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    QString str;

    Label(QWidget* parent, QString text) : QLabel(parent) 
    { 
        this->str = text;
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* p)
    {
        QLabel::paintEvent(p);
        QPainter paint(this);

        QPixmap pixmap;
        pixmap.load(":/pic.png");
        paint.drawPixmap(QRect(0, 0, 32, 32), pixmap);   


        qDebug() << "str: " << str;    
        paint.drawText(QPoint(10, 10), "Hello World");
    }
};



Main::Main(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QLabel* label = new Label(ui.pushButton, "test");

    label.str = "hello world"; // <-- error: expression must have a class type
}
```

How to update the value of `str` from `QLabel* label`?

I tried: `label.str = "hello world";` but I got the error: `expression must have a class type`.

Does subclassing controls increases the app `CPU` usage?

Each time the `paintEvent(QPaintEvent* p)` function is called it creates a new `pixmap` and repaint the control? or the `pixmap` is created only once and kept on memory and then 'reused'?

There's is any 'best practices' when subclassing buttons? or is it desirable to avoid subclassing?

Comment: `static_cast<Label*>(label)->str = "hello world";`

Comment: `label` is a pointer. `.` does not work with pointers.  You may want to look up `->` in you favourite C++ book.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this did work, do you know about the subclassing thing i asked? `n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m` i forgot to mention that `.` also was giving an error, but yes you're right.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions at once.

Comment: Qt widget classes are *meant* to be derived from in order to customize behavior. Witness the abundance of virtual member functions.

Comment: Creating a pixmap anew every time is likely expensive. I see no reason why you can't create it once and stash it in a member variable. There is no magical global cache of pictures, to the best of my knowledge.